# Unable to add more than one string to a list

Tags: python

I started to make a program where you can add a list and than search through it. It was all going fine until an error kept showing up.

```
_list = []
def variables(variable):
    return variable.title()

while True:
    inputt = input("\nPrint c to create/add to a program\nand s to search for"
                   " something that is in that list, enter 'q' when u ready")
    if inputt == 'c':
        while True:
            create_something = input("What is the item you want to add your list")
            _list.append(create_something)
            _list = str(_list)
            print("This is your list so far\n" + _list)
            if create_something == 'q':
                print("This is yo' list so far")
                break
    elif input == 's':
        print("cool")
```

When I try to add more than one item to the list it says that `'str' object has no attribute 'append'`.

Comment: This line `_list = str(_list)` overrides your `list` object with a `string` object, You can't `append` anything to a string because there is no such method for `string` objects.

Comment: You change your list to a string in the line `_list = str(_list)`.

Comment: I have that; in line 12

Comment: Also note there's a typo in the `elif input == 's':` line—it should be `elif inputt == 's':`. The way it is, the condition will never evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

append works only on list and not on string. If you want to convert to string to just print, then consider using `str(_list)` just for the print or use `join` method.

Here is an example using join :

```
_list = []
def variables(variable):
    return variable.title()


while True:
    inputt = input("\nPrint c to create/add to a program\nand s to search for something that is in that list, enter 'q' when u ready")
    if inputt == 'c':
        while True:
            create_something = input("What is the item you want to add your list")
            _list.append(create_something)
            print("This is your list so far\n" + ''.join(_list))
            if create_something == 'q':
                print("This is yo' list so far")
                break

    elif input == 's':
        print("cool")
```

Leaving `_list` as list, however while printing them - use join to print them as string.

```
Print c to create/add to a program
and s to search for something that is in that list, enter 'q' when u ready'c'
What is the item you want to add your list'foo'
This is your list so far
foo
What is the item you want to add your list' bar'
This is your list so far
foo bar
What is the item you want to add your list' baz'
This is your list so far
foo bar baz
```

Answer (score 0):

This line converts `_list` into a string, and it's no longer a list anymore:

```
_list = str(_list)
```

So when your loop executes the second time, it tries to run `_list.append()` and throws the error you reported.

Comment: I have that in line 12

Comment: when I remove it, it prints TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str